# React router not redirect on the exact url

Tags: url, redirect, reactjs, localhost, react-router

I am building an web application in which react-router is used. When i hit the url **localhost:8080/user** it works fine. When i hit **localhost:8080/user/login** it not works and console show **unexpected tokken >** what does it means? I could not understand the problem.

One more thing in this line of code when i changed to any other class then also its not working  .

Routes.js

```
import React from 'react';

import UserBase from './UserBase.js';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard.js';
import Login from './Login.js';

// var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
// var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
// var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link, IndexLink, browserHistory } from 'react-router'


var Routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="user" component={UserBase}>
            <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
);

module.exports = Routes;
```

Login.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Login extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    render(){
        return (
             <div className="login">
              <a className="hiddenanchor" id="signup"></a>
              <a className="hiddenanchor" id="signin"></a>

              <div className="login_wrapper">
                <div className="animate form login_form">
                  <section className="login_content">
                    <form>
                      <h1>Login Form</h1>

                    </form>
                  </section>
                </div>

                <div id="register" className="animate form registration_form">
                  <section className="login_content">
                    <form>
                      <h1>Create Account</h1>

                    </form>
                  </section>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Routes js is working fine if I remove 'history={browserHistory}' means that if I use ugly url i.e. used with #. If I hit http://localhost:8080/#/user/login?_k=jtorvg is working fine then what will be the issue?

I use node server and express package to serve for every request.

```
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/components/EntryPoint.js",
    output: {
        filename:"public/bundle.js"
    },
    module : {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please show `Login.js` component?

Comment: It means there's a syntax error in your login component

Comment: If I changed login component to dashboard component then its also not working. But my dashboard component is working fine

Comment: How do you serve your application? And how your bundle is being build With webpack? It seems like routing isn't passed to react from the server.

Comment: I added my webpack config and server config. How can i check this ? what will be the solution ?

Comment: No, it's not the issue, you are doing everything correct. Does error point's to a certain code line? Could you provide a screen or a stack trace?

Comment: I added a screenshot. Please check it

Comment: And you say that if you change `<Route path="login" component={Login}/>` to `<Route path="login" component={Dashboard}/>` everything works fine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117393/discussion-between-lazarev-alexandr-and-kushal-jain).

Comment: can you provide index.html code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I got the answer after struggling of hours a very small mistake. At index page `bundle.js` script path has to be changed for the url like localhost:8080/user/dashboard.

Just add `<script src="/bundle.js" />` instead of `<script src="bundle.js" />`